# header vs form action

Tags: php, http-headers

I am currently diving into php and html and working on a simple redirect just for the purpose of showing database content through an url.

I know you can generate an URL in 2 ways, probably more but these two are the reason why I started this question:

php:

```
<?php
    header('Location: example.php?parameter');
?>
```

html:

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
<!--input fields etc -->
<input type="submit">
```

But now I was wondering "What is the best practice regarding these two options". Is it just a personal opinion with what you like the best and what is the best suitable way in a situation or is there something else I am overlooking.

I am not trying to start a discussion here, just interested in what is 'normally/commonly' used.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes I know and that's not the reason why I am asking. I prefer doing this with php rather dan html but is there any downside to this method I am using. I can understand that when you need to use a redirect while you are using this method it won't be possible but besides that. Are there any other reasons?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two pieces of code do fundamentally different things, even though in some cases the user-observed behavior may be very similar.

This is a server-initiated redirect:

```
<?php
    header('Location: example.php?parameter');
?>
```

Basically this is the server's way of telling the browser that it should browse to another location.  (The browser can ignore it, but doesn't really have a reason to ignore it.)  Additional details can be added to the response to tell the browser if this redirection is temporary or permanent, or has other conditions regarding it.  But at its simplest this is just the server saying "I don't really have anything for you here, go over there for your information."

This is a client-initiated form POST:

```
<form action="example.php" method="post">
```

Well, "client-initiated" in that the actual action of POSTing the form comes from the browser.  The server probably gave that HTML tag to the client to tell it to do that, but the client is free to change it if it wants.  (There's no reason to do so, though.)  The point here is that this is a means by which the client sends data to `example.php`.  It has nothing to do with redirects, it's just sending data to a specific resource on the server.

The server can respond to that data with a redirect, or a rendered page, or any other response.

These might be used in conjunction in a number of ways.  Let's say you have `page1.php` and `page2.php`.  On `page1` there is a form, and after that form is submitted you want the user to see `page2`.  This is where the user-observed result might be indistinguishable.

`page1` can post to `page2` and `page2` can handle the submitted data and then display.  *Or* `page1` can post back to `page1`, handle the submitted data, and redirect to `page2`.  To the end user, there's essentially no difference.  The main difference is in how you organize your code.  In that regard, sure, personal preference comes into play.  But this isn't the only scenario in which either of these tools are employed.  For example, you might want to submit values to a completely different page for a completely different reason, or redirect on a page request for some server-side reason completely unknown to the client.

As you develop more complex web applications you'll find certain patterns work well in certain situations, and personal preference will begin to conform to those patterns.  In the  end, these are just tools to perform actions (redirect the client to another location, send data to the server) and your overarching patterns and practices simply make use of the tools.

Comment: Thank you. This was exactly the kind of answer I was looking for. I just got a little more insight at the mechanics behind these 2 "methods"!

Answer (score 1):

The HTTP `location` header and a HTML form are not really comparable.

The header should be used if you want to create a redirect during the execution of PHP. The form should be used if you want to submit user input from the client side (browser) to the server side.

HTML anchors are the best way to provide links on a web page:

```
<a href="example.php?parameter">Click</a>
```

Comment: Okay I get it. The only thing is the anchor method won't be suitable when wanting to redirect without clicking. On the other hand when filling out a form you'd either have to click or press enter..

Comment: Use whatever is most suitable and appropriate for the task. Try not to look for a one size fits all approach and instead, look at the benefits and limitations of the available methods and decide based on that.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you use html forms or links. header() is used mainly if you want to redirect an user after the code is executed (e.g. after a successful login, or when is not authorized to access a restricted page)